# My button in cocoa touch app is not returning my position correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, uibutton, invisible

I have an app with a button covering the whole screen and with smaller buttons on top of this button. When I press the button I write a text that shows the position of the finger, but when I put my finger over certain areas, where I can not see anything, the button stops working (lower right area of the screen) I am certain there is nothing there. Here is the code:

.h file:

```
{
    UIButton *BigButton;

    CGPoint FingerPos;
    bool isFingerDown;
    UILabel *FingerPosLabel;
}
-(void)Update;
-(IBAction)FingerMoved:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
-(IBAction)FingerPressed:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
-(IBAction)FingerReleased:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event;
```

.m file

```
{
    viewDidLoad
    {
        BigButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [BigButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 480)];
        [self.view addSubview:BigButton];

        FingerPos = CGPointMake(0, 0);
        isFingerDown = false;
        FingerPosLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50)];
        [self.view addSubview:FingerPosLabel];
        [FingerPosLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1]];
        [FingerPosLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];

        [BigButton addTarget:self action:@selector(FingerPressed:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [BigButton addTarget:self action:@selector(FingerReleased:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [BigButton addTarget:self action:@selector(FingerMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    }

    -(IBAction)FingerPressed:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint endingPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        FingerPos = endingPosition;
        isFingerDown = true;
    }
    -(IBAction)FingerMoved:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint endingPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        FingerPos = endingPosition;
    }
    -(IBAction)FingerReleased:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
        NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint endingPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        FingerPos = endingPosition;
        isFingerDown = false;
    }
```

I an certain there are no buttons or views of any kind above the button BigButton, though there is a button above the invisible area, though far up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question solved. The screen was on landscape and the button was not wide enough. I inverted the width and height (should be 480, 300)

Comment: It wouldn't have helped you with this problem, but in the future you can debug missing touches by turning on "Debug -> Color Blended Layers" in the simulator. Just yesterday it helped me debug a transparent view that was overlapping my button and swallowing touch events.